# Android : Java.Lang.RuntimeException with intent

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am developing two apps on Android: app A which when a button is pressed should open app B which should return a value to app A, like "OK". To do this, app A sends an intent with the action "com.intent.test", but when it receives the intent, app B crashes with the following error message:

Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.newdemo/com.example.newdemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.demointent.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.demointent-SsbNhZc7TrVyMjaIbZDfVw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.demointent-SsbNhZc7TrVyMjaIbZDfVw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.example.demointent-SsbNhZc7TrVyMjaIbZDfVw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]'

AndroidManifest.xml app B :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.example.demointent" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.intent.test" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

MainActivity app B:

```
namespace NewDemo
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
                Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

                Intent receivedIntent = Intent;
                if (receivedIntent == null) return;

                var dataReceived = receivedIntent.GetStringExtra("key");
                var action = receivedIntent.Action;

                var intent = new Intent();
                switch (action)
                {
                    case "com.intent.test":
                        intent.PutExtra("result", "OK");
                        break;
                }

                SetResult(Result.Ok, intent);
                Toast.MakeText(this, "My app is started. Data: " + dataReceived, ToastLength.Short)?.Show();
                Finish();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "error: " + ex.Message, ToastLength.Short)?.Show();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity app A:

```
      protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            var btnstartWithAction = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.btnstartWithAction);
            if (btnstartWithAction != null)
            {
                btnstartWithAction.Click += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    var intent = new Intent();
                    var action = "com.intent.test";
                    intent.SetAction(action);
                    intent.PutExtra("key", "keytest");

                    StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "App"), 3);
                };
            }
        }
```

This error appears when I use the intent with action. When app A call App B with the package name, I don't have a problem. Like this :

```
                   Intent launchIntent = ApplicationContext.PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.newdemo");
                    launchIntent?.SetFlags(0);
                    launchIntent?.SetAction("com.intent.test");
                    launchIntent?.PutExtra("key", "12345");
                    StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(launchIntent, ""), 12);
```

I have already cleaned and built my project several times. I'm coding in c# with Xamarin and visual studio 2022. does anyone have any idea what is going on?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: 'Unable to instantiate activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.newdemo/com.example.newdemo.MainActivity}:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
> "com.example.demointent.MainActivity"

On `Xamarin.Android`, by default, generates the Java wrappers using MD5-based class names to avoid Java class name clashing, such as:

```
 md579731053346ff64fcf21847b09163ce1.MainActivity
```

You have hard-coded a `activity android:name=".MainActivity"` in your manifest but the generated class will be MD5-based by default.

You should avoid to mix up declarative attributes and manually writing the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

`[Activity (Label = "MyApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/ic_launcher")]` is generating a piece of code in the actual used (generated) `AndroidManifest.xml` that looks like:

```
  <activity android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="AndroidApp1" android:name="md5c178831cd46fc53bebc42cf953f78ced.MainActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and your code will be somewhere else. You can find the generated `AndroidManifest.xml` in the output folder `.\obj\Debug\android`.

So,try to remove the manual edits from your manifest file and add your stuff via attributes if you need.

For example:

```
[Activity(Label = "SearchBarDemos", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true,Exported =true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)] 
    [
    IntentFilter
    (
        new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[]
            {
                Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault,
                Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable
            },
        DataSchemes = new[] { "myapp" }
    )
]
    public class MainActivity:Activity
 {

 }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I just spent 3 days figuring out what was wrong, I would have never found out on my own. Thank you so much !